# blogger - problema al aceptar cookies de la pagina dentro de una entrada

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

estuve probando en blogger cosas y cuando quise colocar una **página dentro de otra página** me salían los anuncios de aceptar cookies, pero al aceptar solo actualiza la página y me vuelve a pedir que los acepte sino no me carga los contenidos que se encuentran dentro como los videos y sale una imagen de error

el codigo que probe es del iframe

```
<iframe
    height="1024"
    src=""
    width="100%"
></iframe>
```

es interesante la programación :)